# Word for the noise caused by sea waves striking at beach?

Tags: word-request

Which word can I use to describe the high noise made by ocean waves striking at beach? When there are winds blowing, they make a high noise.

Comment: *Roar of the surf* and *crash of the surf* both have lots of Google hits, though probably not nearly so many as Google reports.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave

Comment: you can use the word 'roaring' for describing the sound of the sea, especially when it is turbulent

Comment: When you say "high noise" do you mean "loud noise" or "high-pitched noise?"  [Hitting a piano key forcefully makes a loud noise.  Hitting a key on the far right of the piano makes a high (pitched) noise.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As StoneyB suggested, *roar* and *crash* of the surf are common descriptions. *[Roar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roar)* is used in sense 4, “Generally, of inanimate objects etc., to make a loud resounding noise”, and   *[crash](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash#Noun)* in sense 3, “A loud sound as made for example by cymbals”.

Some other terms often used include *[pounding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pounding#Adjective)* surf, in sense “Causing heavy or loud throbs”, and *[rumble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rumble)* of surf, in sense  “A low pitched irregular noise, such as that of thunder or a hungry stomach”.

[Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pounding+surf%2Crumbling+surf%2Crumble+of+surf%2Croaring+surf%2Croar+of+surf%2Ccrashing+surf&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) for *pounding surf,rumbling surf,rumble of surf,roaring surf,roar of surf,crashing surf* shows  *pounding surf* coming first since about 1930, before which time *roaring surf*  was most common among those phrases. In recent years, *crashing surf* has pushed *roaring surf* out of second place.  (It is possible other forms and combinations not included in that ngrams, such as  “roar of *the* surf” instead of “roar of surf”, may occur more frequently; feel free to try different phrases, time periods, smoothing, etc.)

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/susurrus), *susurrus* means “A whispering or rustling sound; a murmur”; although *susurrus* obviously doesn't apply to loud surf,  [google for *susurrus of the surf*](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=susurrus+of+the+surf) shows that phrase appearing in several recent books.